# Convert PHP CURL to NPM CURL

Tags: php, node.js, curl, npm, curljs

I am currently attempting to make a CURL request using node.

I have the following CURL request in PHP:-

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: token XXX',
  'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I need to run this same CURL request in node.
I have attempted many different NPM packages and settled on [curljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curljs).

I have the following code:-

```
var curl = require("curljs");

var curlOpts = curl.opts.connect_timeout(10);

curl("https://www.website.com -H Authorization: token XXX -H Content-Type: application/json --get", curlOpts, function(err, data, stderr) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(stderr);
});
```

I am able to get a response from the server without any errors, but it is not returning any data.
I get the following response:-

```
null

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Would anybody be able to help with a push in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On another note:-

I have also tried to use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Here is my code:-

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://www.website.com',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'token XXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
  } else {
    console.log(body);
  }
}

request.get(options, callback);
```

But it keeps returning an error.

Using [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) also returns the same error:-

```
fetch("https://www.website.com", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "token XXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  return response;
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The PHP version works perfectly, am I not configuring the headers correctly?

Comment: I've moved from PHP to Node.  One of the best things about Node is its ability to make HTTP requests.  Do you need to use CURL?  I suspect your task would be better accomplished with a library like RequestJS.  I never want to curl_setopt again :)

Comment: I am attempting to return JSON from an API request.
Would you be able to provide an example using RequestJS?
I am not set on using curljs, just seemed to be the best of the packages I could find.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to get JSON.  My favorite is fetch.  Simply use it like you would on the browser.  npm install node-fetch.  Then `fetch('http://www.website.com').then(res => res.json()).then(res => // do something)`.  If you need authorization headers, that can be done too.  RequestJS can do it too.  Just depends on your preference.  I've used both.

Comment: I haven't used curljs but I did use an npm module called curlrequest that actually spawned a new process to execute the curl request. We were executing 1000s of requests very quickly and it really drove up CPU/memory utilization. Switching to using the built-in HTTP module fixed that issue so I would highly recommend using an HTTP module over curl

Comment: @MattAltepeter How would I go about doing this? Also am I able to pass a authorization token?

Comment: Also I will only be making 1 request a day to the API. Is there anything I can do to make my initial curljs script run?

Comment: the request (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module on NPM is very popular and robust. As far as making your script run once a day you have a couple options: set up a cron job that will start your script whenever you want it to or you could use a `setInterval()` within your process. I would definitely recommend the cron job way though.

Comment: I will be running a cron to run this script. Using request how can I pass an authorization token?

Comment: It could just be your example but I would like to point out that the url `https://www.website.com` is not a valid full url. It needs a slash at the end `https://www.website.com/`. Maybe PHP's Curl adds this automatically which could explain your problem with other methods. Although technically servers can respond to `GET [nothing] HTTP/1.1`, they are probably much happier with `GET / HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requests are baked into Node.js. The `http` and `https` modules are some of the core modules: they are installed without you having to do anything else.

They aren't, however, totally simple to use. They're not complex *per se*, but they could be simpler.

The nicest implementation in my mind is the `fetch` API. This is included in modern web browsers ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)). You can also use it in Node by installing the [`node-fetch` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```
npm install node-fetch --save
```

You can then make your call using the `fetch` function. You get the results, in a nice, modern ES6-ish kind of way, by using `Promise`s.

In your case:

```
fetch("http://www.website.com", {
  method: "GET", // not strictly necessary
  headers: {
    Authorization: "token XXX",
    "Content-Type": "application/json" // is this accurate?!
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json(); // we want JSON output
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response); // logs the server response
});
```

You can make this even prettier if you are willing to use modern arrow functions.

Comment: This is still returning a 404, it;s strange how the PHP version of my script pulls the content from the API but no matter what I have tried with node I keep getting a 404.

Comment: @TonyHensler Some APIs like a nice `User-Agent` set: you could try that. But it's very hard coding against a resource when you don't know what it is!

Comment: I have attempted putting a User-Agent in there but it still returns the same result. It's very frustrating how it works perfectly in PHP but I can't get a response using node.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

I think you can simply use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Example in your scenario:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://www.website.com',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "token XXX",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

The module is simple to use and has a intuitive solutions and examples. We use this in our entire Node project for a while now and no issues encountered yet so far.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: While this does not appear to be [a link-only answer that would be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), links to a tool or library should include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and ideally [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605). "Very simple to use" is an *extremely* minimal recommendation.